# How to perform a group by (sql) in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
code    appearance
----------------
j4t8    1
fj89    3
pf6n    1
j4t8    5
```

And I want to sort by the codes which appear the most. As you can see (and since I want to perform a group by) there are duplicate codes, so using **HashMap** would be a problem (duplicate keys). Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason not to just use an ArrayList and a Comparator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know if this is the best solution but you could create a map of a list like this:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HahsMap<String, List<Integer>>();
if(map.contains.(key))
{
  map.get(key).add(new_appearance_value);
}
else
{
  List<Integer> app = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  app.add(new_appearance_value);
  map.put(key, app);
}
```

Where the map key would be the code and the values of appearance would go into the list.

Note: to determine which code has more appearances just check for the size of the list of each code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

The appearances will be stored in a list associated with every code.
Then given a code you just retrieve the list of integers and iterate over it.

Comment: How is this collection sorted? How do you quickly determine which code has the most appearances?

Comment: @Lugo, you can use SortedList with custom Comparator if you need specific sort. Otherwise, use default Comparator (natural order)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Collection of Pair objects. Each pair holds the code and the appearance. You then sort the collection using a Comparator, which only compares the appearance in each Pair object, and disregards the code.

Answer (score 0):

The Commons Collections [MultiValueMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html) can be used to decorate another map, allowing it to have more than one value for a key.